# How to create a dictionary mapping on custom dictionary in Racket?

Tags: list, dictionary, racket, bnf, redex

I have defined dictionary as this judgment in BNF grammar:

```
d ::= () (any boolean) (list cons d d)
```

Meaning, dictionaries are empty, or (any boolean) or a list of such pairs.

If I want to create a mapping, say "a true", how do I do it?

If I do

```
(define-values (d) (values '(a true)))
```

it just creates a new d, doesn't map to previous judgment d defined.

Comment: You mean `'((a . true))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want your dictionary to be just an association list:

```
(define d (list (cons 'x #t) (cons 'y #f)))
```

Depending on how are you going to implement the add operation you could either `set!` a new mapping:

```
(set! d (cons (cons 'z #t) d))
```

Or just create a new list (preferred):

```
(define d (list (cons 'z #t) (cons 'x #t) (cons 'y #f)))
```

Either way, the dictionary `d` will have the new mapping in the expected format:

```
'((z . #t) (x . #t) (y . #f))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Oscar